# QGIS and Shapely : Shell is not a LinearRing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, shapely, geos

When trying to create a polygon with `Shapely` with QGIS python console, i'm getting the error :

```
ValueError: Null geometry supports no operations
```

And it prints `Shell is not a LinearRing` in the console.

```
 layer = QgsVectorLayer(myshapefile, "testlayer_shp", "ogr")
 geom = next(layer.getFeatures()).geometry()
 multiPolygon = geom.get()
 pointList = multiPolygon.coordinateSequence()[0][0]
 poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[p.x(), p.y()] for p in pointList])
```

I first tried doing this with `geopandas`, but I get the same error and I assume it comes from the `Shapely` package. I installed `Shapely` with the [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely)'s python packages.

I'm running it with QGIS python36 on windows10 and I don't have any error when running it directly from this python, only when trying to launch it in QGIS python console.

---

My pip info:

```
alabaster==0.7.10
astroid==1.6.3
Babel==2.5.3
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==2.1.3
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
click-plugins==1.0.3
cligj==0.4.0
cloudpickle==0.5.2
colorama==0.3.9
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.2.1
descartes==1.1.0
Django==2.0.5
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.2.3
ExifRead==2.1.2
fiona==1.7.11
Flask==1.0.2
future==0.16.0
GDAL==2.2.4
geographiclib==1.49
geopandas==0.3.0
geopy==1.13.0
geos==0.2.1
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.10.2
idna==2.6
image==1.5.20
imagesize==1.0.0
ipykernel==4.8.2
ipython==6.3.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.12.0
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lxml==4.2.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.3
mock==2.0.0
munch==2.3.1
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.1
nose2==0.6.5
numpy==1.14.2
numpydoc==0.8.0
osmnx==0.7.4
OWSLib==0.14.0
packaging==17.1
pandas==0.22.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.2.0
pbr==1.10.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.1.0
plotly==2.5.1
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
psutil==5.4.5
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
PuLP==1.6.8
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pyflakes==1.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pylint==1.8.4
pyodbc==4.0.9
pyparsing==2.1.10
pypiwin32==220
pyproj==1.9.5.1
PyQt5==5.9.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2018.3
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==17.0.0
QtAwesome==0.4.4
qtconsole==4.3.1
QtPy==1.4.0
requests==2.18.4
rope==0.10.7
Rtree==0.8.3
scipy==0.19.0rc2
Shapely==1.6.4.post1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.10.0
sip==4.19.8
six==1.11.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
Sphinx==1.7.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.1
spyder==3.2.8
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==5.0.2
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
xlrd==1.0.0
xlwt==1.2.0
```

Comment: My first thought was that you're not closing your polygon, but if it works in standalone Python that's probably not the case.

Comment: I'm curious why you need shapely here - shapely is more or less a wrapper for the geos library, and the same geos functionality is exposed directly through the QgsGeometry API. By using the QgsGeometry methods directly you save converting the features  from QGIS->python lists->shapely geometries->GEOS and instead only do single conversion from QGIS->GEOS. So should be MUCH faster and less coding required in your script!

Comment: I do not need directly Shapely, but i need it when using the OSMNX library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Qgis was using its own version of the GEOS library and Shapely its own too. So when launching my script from QGIS, shapely was trying to use QGIS's GEOS instead of his. I simply fixed it by uninstalling Shapely and installing it with (as mentionned in the github readme):

```
pip install shapely --no-binary shapely
```